# Find the last element of a list

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge

Find the last element of a list from [codewars.com](http://www.codewars.com/kata/541629460b198da04e000bb9/train/ruby)

> Example:
>
> ```
> last( [1,2,3,4] ) # => 4
>
> last( "xyz" ) # => z
>
> last( 1,2,3,4 ) # => 4
> ```

I completed this kata several times tonight.  My current answer is a mashup of several other people's solutions.

1. I do not understand why I cant change .respond_to?(:index) into .is_a? Array
2. Should I use ternary operators in Ruby?
3. Other suggestions?

   ```
   def last (*arg, arg_last)
     arg_last.respond_to?(:index) ? arg_last[-1] : arg_last
   end
   ```

Comment: I find the challenge ambiguous: what should be the result of `last(1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6])` — `[4, 5, 6]` or just `6`?

Answer (score 4):

1. Your input might be a String or an Array. Both of these support the :index method, so foo[-1] will give the last character of a string or the last element of an array. But if you test for it being an array, the solution won't work for strings when it otherwise would.
2. I don't think there's anything wrong with using ternary operators in ruby, as long as all three 'elements' are fairly short. More concise code is easier to read. See the Ruby Style Guide at https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#ternary-operator.

Answer (score 2):

Using the built-in is much simpler

```
array.last
```

If you must implement it without using this built-in, the simplest strategy I can think of is

```
def last(array)
    array.reverse.first
end
```

If you want to convert to an array if it isn't already the Array method will do exactly that

```
def last(a)
    Array(a).last
end
```

1. Using `respond_to?` is better because ([quoting a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769739/determining-type-of-an-object-in-ruby)):

> Normally type checking is not done in Ruby, but instead objects are
>   assessed based on their ability to respond to particular methods,
>   commonly called called "Duck typing". In other words, if it responds
>   to the methods you want, there's no reason to be particular about the
>   type.

2. In my opinion ternary operators should always be avoided, code is read much more often than it is written so writing one or two line less decreasing readibility is not good. Still this is personal style.

---

The function above does not work for strings as a comment pointed out, if you want to add string support it becomes a little bit longer

```
def last(a)
    if a.respond_to?(:each_char)
        Array(a.each_char).last
    else
        Array(a).last
    end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the requirements: There is no String#last method, and it won't return the last arg when multiple arguments are passed.

Comment: 1. You imply that ternary operations are less readable than alternatives. That's an opinion, not a fact, an opinion that not all readers share. 2. I've never seen `Array(a.each_char).last` to extract the last character of a string `a`, no doubt because `a[-1]` is the obvious way to do that. 3. As @sockmock pointed out, `last( 1,2,3,4 )` raises an exception when your code is run. Either you didn't test your code or presented it knowing it did not meet the spec. Neither are acceptable. Nor is it acceptable to let an answer stand that has been shown to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question was answered nicely by @sockmonk. You could have written `arg.last.is_a? String || arg.last.is_a? Array`, which, though longer, is arguably clearer.

Regarding the second question, I suppose that's a matter of individual preference, but I am happy to use a ternary operator when it fits comfortably on one line. One reason is that it reads fasters than an `if` clause or `case` statement, as we humans have greater experience reading horizontally than vertically.

@200_success makes an important point in his comment on the question. For the example he gave:

```
last(1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6])
```

your solution would return `6`, but for

```
last(1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6]])
```

it would return `[6]`. What is the rational for that? Moreover, the question asks for the last item in the list, not the last item in the last list of the list. I think the only reasonable interpretation would have `list` return `[4,5,6]` in @200_success's example. To do that, you can modify your code as I have done below.

**Code**

```
def last(*args, e)
  case args.empty?
  when true
    case e
    when Array, String then e[-1]
    else e
    end
  else e
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
last( [1,2,3,4] )        #=> 4 
last( "xyz" )            #=> "z" 
last( 8 )                #=> 8 
last( 1,2,3,4 )          #=> 4 
last( ["abc"], "xyz" )   #=> "xyz" 
last( "abc", "xyz" )     #=> "xyz" 
last( 1,2,3,[4] )        #=> [4]
```

**Explanation**

To see the value of `e` for different arguments, change `last` to:

```
def last(*args, e)
  puts "args = #{args}, e = #{e}"
end
```

and execute that for each of the examples above:

```
last( [1,2,3,4] )      # < will return 4     >
  #=> "args = [], e = [1, 2, 3, 4]" 
last( "xyz" )          # < will return "z"   >
  #=> "args = [], e = xyz" 
last( 8 )              # < will return 8     > 
  #=> "args = [], e = 8" 
last( 1,2,3,4 )        # < will return 4     >
  #=> "args = [1, 2, 3], e = 4" 
last( ["abc"], "xyz" ) # < will return "xyz" >
  #=> "args = [["abc"]], e = xyz" 
last( "abc", "xyz" )   # < will return "xyz" >
  #=> "args = ["abc"], e = xyz" 
last( 1,2,3,[4] )      # < will return [4]   >
  #=> "args = [1, 2, 3], e = [4]"
```

We consider two cases:

- args is empty
- args is non-empty

The second is the easiest: we simply return `e`. That applies to the last four examples.

It the first case, if `e` is:

```
- an array, the last element, e[-1], is returned   (example #1)
- a string, the last character, e[-1], is returned (example #2)
- a literal, e is returned                         (example #3)
```